# How can i add one more filed for image upload and show?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

can add one more field for image that saved in mysql i am unable to add by js

this is my index.php script how can i add image field in this script just want to show image from mysql

**index.php**

```
<body>  
        <div class="container">  
   <br />
   <div class="table-responsive">  

    <div id="grid_table"></div>
   </div>  
  </div>
    </body>  
</html>  
<script>

    $('#grid_table').jsGrid({

     width: "100%",
     height: "600px",

     filtering: true,
     inserting:true,
     editing: true,
     sorting: true,
     paging: true,
     autoload: true,
     pageSize: 10,
     pageButtonCount: 5,
     deleteConfirm: "Do you really want to delete data?",

     controller: {
      loadData: function(filter){
       return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "fetch_data.php",
        data: filter
       });
      },
      insertItem: function(item){
       return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "fetch_data.php",
        data:item
       });
      },
      updateItem: function(item){
       return $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: "fetch_data.php",
        data: item
       });
      },
      deleteItem: function(item){
       return $.ajax({
        type: "DELETE",
        url: "fetch_data.php",
        data: item
       });
      },
     },

     fields: [
      {
       name: "id",
    type: "hidden",
    css: 'hide'
      },
      {
       name: "first_name", 
    type: "text", 
    width: 150, 
    validate: "required"
      },
      {
       name: "last_name", 
    type: "text", 
    width: 150, 
    validate: "required"
      },
      {
       name: "age", 
    type: "text", 
    width: 50, 
    validate: function(value)
    {
     if(value > 0)
     {
      return true;
     }
    }
      },
      {
       name: "gender", 
    type: "select", 
    items: [
     { Name: "", Id: '' },
     { Name: "Male", Id: 'male' },
     { Name: "Female", Id: 'female' }
    ], 
    valueField: "Id", 
    textField: "Name", 
    validate: "required"
      },
      {
       type: "control"
      }
     ]

    });

</script>
```

this my fetch_data.php file how can i add image field in this script just want to show image from mysql

**fetch_data.php**

```
<?php

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testing", "root", "");

$method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

if($method == 'GET')
{
 $data = array(
  ':first_name'   => "%" . $_GET['first_name'] . "%",
  ':last_name'   => "%" . $_GET['last_name'] . "%",
  ':age'     => "%" . $_GET['age'] . "%",
  ':gender'    => "%" . $_GET['gender'] . "%"
 );
 $query = "SELECT * FROM sample_data WHERE first_name LIKE :first_name AND last_name LIKE :last_name AND age LIKE :age AND gender LIKE :gender ORDER BY id DESC";

 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute($data);
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
  $output[] = array(
   'id'    => $row['id'],   
   'first_name'  => $row['first_name'],
   'last_name'   => $row['last_name'],
   'age'    => $row['age'],
   'gender'   => $row['gender']
  );
 }
 header("Content-Type: application/json");
 echo json_encode($output);
}

if($method == "POST")
{
 $data = array(
  ':first_name'  => $_POST['first_name'],
  ':last_name'  => $_POST["last_name"],
  ':age'    => $_POST["age"],
  ':gender'   => $_POST["gender"]
 );

 $query = "INSERT INTO sample_data (first_name, last_name, age, gender) VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :age, :gender)";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute($data);
}

if($method == 'PUT')
{
 parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $_PUT);
 $data = array(
  ':id'   => $_PUT['id'],
  ':first_name' => $_PUT['first_name'],
  ':last_name' => $_PUT['last_name'],
  ':age'   => $_PUT['age'],
  ':gender'  => $_PUT['gender']
 );
 $query = "
 UPDATE sample_data 
 SET first_name = :first_name, 
 last_name = :last_name, 
 age = :age, 
 gender = :gender 
 WHERE id = :id
 ";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute($data);
}

if($method == "DELETE")
{
 parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $_DELETE);
 $query = "DELETE FROM sample_data WHERE id = '".$_DELETE["id"]."'";
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
}

?>
```

Comment: First of all, please format that code properly. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Your delete query is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Why does the DELETE query not use proper parameterisation like all the others? It's just asking for trouble.

Comment: Anyway if you are going to return an image in a JSON response, you can either a) provide a base64-encoded string version of the image in a property of the JSON, or b) provide a URL path to the image file (if such exists) or to a script URL which (when given an image ID) will fetch the relevant image data from the DB and return it in binary format). Either of these can then be used by the receiving JavaScript to set the "src" property of an "img" tag in HTML, and display the image. What you _can't_ do is return the binary image data direct in the JSON, because JSON is a text format.